# Вывод статей в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Только начал изучать `React.`

Есть два вопроса.

1) Необходимо создать приложение, выполняющее по сути роль блога, куда возможно добавлять статьи с небольшим разделением по рубрикам и добавлять заметки с небольшим текстом. Предполагаю использование для реализации `react` с `flux` и в качестве `DB` использовать `Mongodb`. Не сломаю голову себе?Это возможно?ПО идее я уже заметки реализовал, вроде все работает норм.

2) Как ограничить количество выводимых на странице статей? Конечно же, чтобы они подгружались, а не были новой страницей. Как `frame`. Подскажите примерное направление. Код писать не обязательно.

Comment: "Сломаете" ли вы себе голову - вам виднее. А разбиение на страницы с подгрузкой Ajax-ом делается не сложно: на серверной стороне можно ограничиться всего одним action-ом, который будет отдавать записи по указанным сдвигу и количеству. А на клиенте подтягивать при необходимости записи до тех пор, пока сервер не начнёт возвращать пустой список.

Comment: Логично. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

1) Если ты с этим стеком хорошо знаком, то голову не сломаешь. Но для простоты работы можно и без flux работать, а все данные держать в стейте контейнера (Этот подход уже не раз показал свою эффективность).

2) У тебя на бэкэнде должен быть метод, который умеет возвращать данные по частям например `/items?top=0&count=10` - вернет тебе первые 10 элементов, 
метод `/items?top=10&count=20` вернет тебе 20 элементов, начиная с 10. Надеюсь ты понял логику =) Далее ты отслеживаешь в компоненте реакта скролл страницы и если он подходит к концу, тогда ты загружаешь следующие N элементов, начиная с 10, то есть `/items?top=10&count=N`. Если нужна более подробная реализация - пиши.

Comment: Оу, спасибо за ответ. Со стеком знаком не очень. Как раз пытаюсь учить. Дочь просто попросила написать ей небольшой блог, вот и размышляю, попробовать реализовать это на реакте и заодно поучится. Ок, если что напишу. Спасибо еще раз за ответ.